# How to use a pop-up menu in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to use a pop-up menu when I click on a plus icon in the navigation bar that looks like the pic I attached. Can you please instruct me how can I accomplish that?

[image]

Thanks a bunch!

Thanks for the help guys, I got my answer, and if someone is looking for a direct link to the apple documentation here it is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActionSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIActionSheet

Comment: Looks like a UIActionSheet. Look at the class reference for how to proceed.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As rdelmar says, that's a UIActionSheet. @rdelmar, you should post that as an answer so the OP can accept it.

You would add a UIBarButtonItem built from a custom view (a button) and attach an action to the button that invokes and displays a UIActionSheet.

### EDIT:

This is VERY old thread. UIActionSheet has been deprecated for years, and the right solution now is to use the action sheet appearance of a UIAlertController

Comment: @JohnBigs, since you're a beginner, you might want to spend some time looking at Apple's "Human Interface Guidelines" document. It will be very helpful to you to see how Apple thinks you should create an app, and how (and when) to use various UI elements.

Comment: @rdelmar yes you right, i did. I followed the "start developing iOS apps today" guid and learned how to create a todo app with apple guidance. Now I want to try to create a notes app myself...it's kind of similar but I want to make it a bit more advanced, so hopefully I succeed and it will be a good lesson..

Comment: UIActionSheet has been deprecated in iOS 8 and later. Instead use UIAlertController https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

Comment: @Mastergalen Yup. If you look, you'll notice that my answer was from early 2014 (over 5 years ago.) Now the answer has changed. UIActionSheet is long-deprecated and you should instead use the action sheet appearance on a UIAlertController.