# Can you identify this standard iPhone/Swift white overlay with rounded corners?

Tags: iphone, swift

I am seeing the following [popup/overlay] menu in a number of apps [Twitter, in this case] and I'm wondering if it is a standard Swift component/library/etc., and if so if anyone knows where I might find it please, thank you? JBM

[image: screen shot of pop up overlay menu from twitter app]

Comment: `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` as the `UIAlertControllerStyle` ?

Comment: Thanks Larme, I thought this would be an easy one to answer.

Comment: from iOS 9 sheets have rounded corners

Comment: @Larme, if you wanna add that as an answer, I will happily accept it as so?

Comment: I pointed out the same components in the answers of @Dharmesh Kheni. I don't think that I need to post a duplicate answer. You can mark Dharmesh Kheni's one if it answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a pop-up menu in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751964/how-to-use-a-pop-up-menu-in-ios)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Larme commented it is an `UIAlertController` with the `ActionSheet` style.

Consider below code:

```
@IBAction func showActionSheet(sender: AnyObject) {
    // 1
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    // 2
    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File Deleted")
    })
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("File Saved")
    })

    //
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })


    // 4
    optionMenu.addAction(deleteAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(saveAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    // 5
    self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

1. an UIAlertController with the ActionSheet style is created
2. two actions are created which can be added to the Alert Controller. Note the use of a closure inside the brackets of the handler parameter
3. another action is created, this time with the Cancel style
4. the actions are added to the Alert Controller
5. The Alert Controller is presented.

And your result will be:

[image]

You can modify it as per your need.

For more Info refer [this](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/action-sheet-tutorial-ios8-swift) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh. Although strictly speaking I was not looking for these components, they are of course useful to know about.